# Filtering for multiple strings on f.read

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ive been playing with various ways to filter multiple strings on `f.read()`. I cant seem to find one that works as Id expect it to, apart from multiple separate loops but I refuse to believe there isn't a more elegant solution.

I am trying to do something akin to:

```
if 'string' or 'string2' or 'string3' in f.read():
```

I have tried a few variations such as:

```
if ('string1', 'string2','string3') in f.read():

if f.read() ('string1', 'string2','string3'):
```

Of course I've not found a way that is working in the manner I would expect, and as google and the docs are failing to, could anyone enlighten me?

After Kasramvd's enlightenment the below shows both elegance and function. Take note of the finale line specifically.

```
check_list = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
for filename in files:
     f = open(root + filename)
     fi = f.read()
     if any(i in fi for i in check_list):
```

Comment: Do you need to know whether 'string1', 'string2' and 'string3' are lines in f?

Comment: Yes, apologies. Im looking to see if those anyone of those strings are in the read data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close in your fist code but you need to use `or` between conditions not objects, so you can change it to following :

```
with open('file_name') as f:
    fi = f.read()
    if 'string' in fi or 'string2' in fi or 'string3' in fi:
```

But instead of that you can use built-in function `any` :

```
with open('file_name') as f:
    fi = f.read()
    if any(i in fi for i in word_set)
```

And if you are dealing with a huge file instead of loading the whole of file content in memory you can check the existence of strings in each line with a function :

```
def my_func(word_set):
    with open('file_name') as f:
        for line in f:
            if any(i in line for i in word_set):
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: Arr yes I the `any` function ! `if any(i in fi for i in word_set)` looks to be nice and elegant too. Thanks Kasramvd

Comment: You can also apply `any()` to the file itself, because it's an iterable.

Answer (score -1):

You can take them in a list an then compare:

```
lst=['string','string2','string3']
any(l in f.read() for l in lst)
```

Comment: any(['string', 'spam', 'eggs']) will return True if there is a non-empty string in the list, so it doesn't check for the strings in f.read().

Comment: This doesn't work, `any([...])` always returns a boolean.

Comment: Fixed. Look at this now.